# Unable to get subclassed UITableViewCells to display data from successfully queried Parse objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, parse-platform

*This question has been successfully answered; thank you to jsksma2.*

I cannot get my data to fill the rows in my TableView, even though I get the data back properly and can hard-code the tableview to display a static amount of dummy text. I have a hunch my issue relates to initWithStyle vs initWithCoder for subclassed UITableViewCells.

In a subclass of UITableViewController called "GiveItemsTableViewC", during viewDidLoad I am querying Parse for objects each called "PFGiveItem". I get these back and add each one to a global variable, a mutable array called "myGiveItems". I log these, and I get what I am looking for, so that part is working.

**GiveItemsTableViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"giveItem"];
    [query whereKey:@"giver" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.myGiveItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                PFGiveItem *newGiveItem = [[PFGiveItem alloc]init];
                newGiveItem.giveItemName = object[@"giveItemTitle"];
                newGiveItem.giveItemImage = object[@"giveItemPhoto"];
                [self.myGiveItems addObject:newGiveItem];
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }

    }];
}
```

Now I am trying to load each one of these giveItems into a TableView object, using custom TableViewCells each called "GiveItemCell."

**GiveItemCell.m**

```
@implementation JFGiveItemCell



@synthesize giveItemImageView = _giveItemImageView;
@synthesize giveItemLabel = _giveItemLabel;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Back in the table view controller, I return one section for the table view. 
And when I include a static number for the rowsInSection, I can output test values to each cell. If I execute the code below, I will get a tableView with cells with the label of "Test", as per the upcoming cellForRowAtIndexPath method. So it works with that test, but obviously I'm looking to dynamically load the proper information.

**GiveItemsTableViewController**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 4;
}


- (JFGiveItemCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    JFGiveItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[JFGiveItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    //    PFGiveItem *giveItem = self.myGiveItems[indexPath.row];
    //    cell.giveItemLabel.text = giveItem.giveItemName;
    cell.giveItemLabel.text = @"Test";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Exact problem is that I cannot get the TableViewCells to appear with the label I want. In fact, when attempting to dynamically load the label text and row count (as opposed to with hard-coded placeholders), I cannot get ANY labels or the proper number of rows at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're forgetting to call `[tableView reloadData]` in the callback of your block method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"giveItem"];
    [query whereKey:@"giver" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.myGiveItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                PFGiveItem *newGiveItem = [[PFGiveItem alloc]init];
                newGiveItem.giveItemName = object[@"giveItemTitle"];
                newGiveItem.giveItemImage = object[@"giveItemPhoto"];
                [self.myGiveItems addObject:newGiveItem];
            }
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }

    }];
}
```

Also, I second @CrimsonChris in saying that you need to set your dataSource methods properly:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return self.myGiveItems.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems...

Your numberOfRowsInSection should return the size of your myGiveItems array.

You need to tell your table view to reload when you finish loading your items asynchronously.

You don't need to implement number of sections, it defaults to 1.

Comment: I was using "return 4" just to see if it works when hard-coded, which it does.

When i use "return self.myGiveItems.count," the table cells do not display properly.